# boto3 issue checking ec2 instance state

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, aws-lambda, boto3

So i have this boto3 script that starts an ec2 instance. But when i run this lambda function, the function describe_instance_status returns blank InstanceStatus array. So the program terminates, after saying index our of range. Any suggestions?

```
import boto3
from time import sleep
region = 'your region name'


def lambda_handler(event, context):

 cye_production_web_server_2 = 'abcdefgh'

 ec2 = boto3.client('ec2',region)

 start_response = ec2.start_instances(
    InstanceIds=[cye_production_web_server_2, ],
    DryRun=False
 )

 print(
    'instance id:',
    start_response['StartingInstances'][0]['InstanceId'],
    'is',
    start_response['StartingInstances'][0]['CurrentState']['Name']
 )

 status = None
 counter = 5
 while (status != 'ok' and counter > 0):
    status_response = ec2.describe_instance_status(
        DryRun=False,
        InstanceIds=[cye_production_web_server_2, ],
    )
    status = status_response['InstanceStatuses'][0]['SystemStatus']      ['Status']
    sleep(5)    # 5 second throttle
    counter=counter-1

 print(status_response)
 print('status is', status.capitalize())
```

Comment: Did you check the lambda (cloudwatch) log for any error message?

Comment: list index out of range: IndexError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 31, in lambda_handler
status = status_response['InstanceStatuses'][0]['SystemStatus']['Status']
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Are you sure this worked as a standalone script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, only running instances are described, unless specified otherwise.

It can take a few minutes for the instance to enter the running state.

Your program will never sleep as it fails in the prior step where the status is actually not returned in first iteration.

Use "IncludeAllInstances" which is a boolean request parameter, when true, includes the health status for all instances. When false, includes the health status for running instances only. Default is false

Answer (score 0):

As omuthu mentioned, the default return type gives info only about the running state of an instance. To get the other states of the instant set the "*IncludeAllInstances*" argument to *describe_instance_status*() as True.